# nginx reverse proxy to apache server - only fulfill nginx forwarded requests

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

Had a question as to what this is called and if it is even possible...

I have my main app on an nginx server.  I have my blog on an apache server that is seperate for security.  Both servers have different IPs.

I am reverse proxying `domain.com/blog` requests to the wordpress apache server for the response.  Is there a way to setup the apache .conf to only fulfill requests that are proxied through the nginx server?  I don't want someone to be able to visit the apache/wordpress ip address directly and run the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think this will do it:

```
<Directory /mydirectory>

    Order Allow,Deny

    Allow from 0.0.0.0 #ip
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/8

</Directory>
```